# Bootstrap 3 ajax content popover is not dismissing on IOS,Safari

Tags: ios, popover, dismiss

I'm experiencing a problem with bootstrap popover on IOS devices. Have found several articles about undismissable bootstrap focus trigger, as well as a popover problems, but none of them has a solution that would work for me.
Here is what i use to get html popover content, unfortunately as soon as a popover is open on a link you cant close it anymore on IOS devices which is a big problem for mobile device users as the only solution is to refresh the actual page to close a popover. Does anyone know a solution on how to make this work on IOS? I have tested on IPhone 6:
HTML

```
<a href="#details" class="details" data-id="106956" data-type="newly added" data-subtype="basket" data-original-title="" title="">Details</a>
```

JQuery

```
$("a.details").off().on("click", function(e) {
    var el=$(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: 'action=details&id=' + el.data("id") + '&type=' + el.data("type") + '&subtype=' + el.data("subtype"), 
        success: function(d){
            el.popover({ content: d.content,
                        container:'.container.post-wrap',
                        placement:'bottom', 
                        html:true, 
                        trigger:'click focus',
                        viewport:'body',
                        role:'button'}).popover("show");
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```